# pdfquery to excel(python)

Tags: pandas, pdf

i am write a simple code with pdfquery to extract data from pdf file. Everything works fine until two values ​​with the same names appear. How can i grab text from selected location? Need to take information where it is circled in blue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4FBF.png)

```
import pdfquery
import pandas as pd

pdf_files = ['sujungta.pdf']

pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery('sujungta.pdf')

total_pages = pdf.doc.catalog['Pages'].resolve()['Count']
print(total_pages)

def clean_text_data(text):
  return text.split(':')[1]

def clean_text_data1(text):
  return text.split('%')[1]

def clean_text_data2(text):
  return text.split('.')[1]

   
def pdf_to_df(pdf_files):

        patient_data = {"Suma, EUR": [],
                        'Dokumento data': [],
                        'Suma apmokėjimui':[],
                        'PVM':[],
                        'PVM SĄSKAITA FAKTŪRA NR':[]                                    
                       }

        for i in range(total_pages): 
                pdf.load(i)

                patient_data["Dokumento data"].append(clean_text_data(pdf.pq('LTText\LineHorizontal:contains("Dokumento data")').text()))
                patient_data["Suma, EUR"].append(clean_text_data(pdf.pq('LTText\LineHorizontal:contains("Suma, EUR")').text()))
                patient_data["Suma apmokėjimui"].append(clean_text_data(pdf.pq('LTText\LineHorizontal:contains("Suma apmokėjimui")').text()))
                patient_data["PVM"].append(clean_text_data1(pdf.pq('LTText\LineHorizontal:contains("PVM")').text()))
                patient_data["PVM SĄSKAITA FAKTŪRA NR"].append(clean_text_data2(pdf.pq('LTText\LineHorizontal:contains("PVM SĄSKAITA FAKTŪRA NR")').text()))
                


        columns=["Dokumento data","Suma, EUR","Suma apmokėjimui", "PVM", "PVM SĄSKAITA FAKTŪRA NR"]

        pdata = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(patient_data)
        pdata = pdata[columns]
        
        return pdata     

pdata = pdf_to_df(pdf_files)
print(pdata)

pdata.to_excel('sąskaitos.xlsx')
```

I will try to take with cooedinates, but data are dynamic, so i cant get what i need.